Flutter String error declared headerLabel but not found
Couldn't find headerLabel to use it. Tried to use variable headerLabel but could not find solution
class ProfileHeaderLabel extends StatelessWidget {
  final String headerLabel;
  const ProfileHeaderLabel({
   Key? key, required this.headerLabel
  }): super(key: key)

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 40,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: const [
          SizedBox(
            height: 40,
            width: 50,
            child: Divider(
              color: Colors.grey,
              thickness: 1,
            ),
          ),
          // 'Account info'
          Text(
            headerLabel,
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
          ),


Couldn't find headerLabel to use it.

In your code:
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
        height: 40,
        child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: const [ // --> This line
        SizedBox(

you're trying to use a non-constant expression (headerLabel) inside a constant (const [...]).
But in your case, headerLabel is not a constant because its value is determined at runtime, not at compile-time.
To solve the issue, just remove const from the Row's children:
 Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [ // Remove `const`
        SizedBox(

Related: (to learn more about const)

What is the difference between the "const" and "final" keywords in Dart?


Thank you @MendelG like the way you put it above works, also putting const before Sizedbox
not before [
Like this:
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          const SizedBox(



You need to add semicolon at the end of your constructor
const ProfileHeaderLabel({
Key? key, required this.headerLabel
}): super(key: key);

You need to remove const keyword after Row children


You're trying to access the non-const variable (headerLabel) that's why it is throwing the error.
